# displaying alert message in mvc3 controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BasicInfStep0( PricingPackModel pricingPackModel)
    {
        bool isEventSaved = false;
        try
        {
            string Zip = pricingPackModel.ZipCode;
            string AccCode = pricingPackModel.CustomerId;
            bool ischeck = pricingPackModel.IsNewAccount;
            isEventSaved = _crmClient.ValidateCodes(Zip, AccCode, ischeck, _authentication, _identity);

            if (isEventSaved)
            {
                return View("BasicInf");
                //return Json(isEventSaved, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



            }
            else
            {
                //return Json(isEventSaved, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //Console.WriteLine("");
                return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Enter the proper value for zipcode');</script>");


            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }


    }
```

I am using this code in my controller,it is displaying the alert message 
but if I click on `OK` button, it's not going back to original screen, it is just showing a white screen.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

if it is all about the `javascript` result then you can also try with this

```
else
{
    return new JavascriptResult { Script = "alert('Enter the proper value for zipcode');" };
}
```